# Auto Smooth looks strange ( custom split normals are not the problem )

Tags: shaders

I gave Suzanne a voxel Ramesh, activated shade smoothing, activated auto smooth and there are no custom split normals to clear up like it's mostly the solution... What exactly is causing the mesh to look this " grid " way? How can I make it look smooth when all the usual solutions fail?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you've subdivided it and it tends to flatten the faces, could you please share the object?

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=mNQZSxd4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/mNQZSxd4/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what you've done previously, but anyway your mesh is very dense and it looks like you've subdivided wrongly, like for example you've used the <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Subdivide* operation instead of applying a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, doing that will add edge loops without rounding the faces, it will even tend to flatten the faces. Even with a *Smoothness* value of 1, the *Subdivide* operation won't act like the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. You can try to smooth with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > *Smooth Vertices* operation (with *Smoothing* value at 1 and *Repeat* at 6), or use the *Smooth* modifier, it will tend to smooth the edges though:

[image]